# Can "to seed" and "to sow" be used interchangeably?

Tags: meaning, verbs, synonyms

I'd never heard about "to sow" until recently, and I was quite surprised that I couldn't find even a connotation about the difference in meaning from "to seed."

The German word "säen" is translated with both "to seed" and "to sow", neither of them are marked dialect or old-fashioned or anything.

Wiktionary defines them as:

1. to seed: To plant or sow an area with seeds.
2. to sow: To scatter, disperse, or plant (seeds).

As a non-native speaker, I fail to see the difference here (especially when one is defined using the other).

In this sense, can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be at least initially addressed using commonly-available references should show signs of such research.

Comment: There aren't many situations in which they *can* be used interchangeably.

Comment: @psmears ... I'm sure you're right that they're less likely to be interchangeable than not, but I can think of at least a few examples where either verb would do. "To sow/seed a lawn", for example.

Comment: @ArchContrarian: Yeah, that's why I didn't go for "never" :-) But in general they mostly take a different sort of object (for the most part "sow" takes the "seed" - literal or metaphorical - being sown, and "seed" takes the location they're being planted in), and both (especially "sow") are mostly used transitively. But as you point out, there are some exceptions :-)

Comment: "to seed" also is used metaphorically outside of plants. For example, "to seed clouds" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_seeding) or also in IT you can talk about seeding in the sense of providing material for a program/function to use or in p2p networks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seeding_(computing)

Comment: Tip: to figure out differences in usage, take a look at example sentences and expressions, which will be listed in a good dictionary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, they can't always be used interchangeably. To *sow* seeds is to put or spread them where you want them to grow, or you can speak of *sowing* a particular type of plant. You can *seed* a patch of ground (sow seeds on it), but 'seed' as a verb can also mean to produce seeds (of a plant), to remove the seeds from a fruit, as well as the various metaphorical uses mentioned by user067531.

Comment: Also, you can sow an idea, but you can't seed an idea.

Answer (score 9):

I think that one main difference is the financial/tech usage of seed vs sow:

3. *Transitive* [To seed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seed) (Wiktionary) :

> To start; to provide, assign or determine the initial resources for, position of, state of.
>
> *A venture capitalist **seeds** young companies.
>
>   The tournament coordinator will **seed** the starting lineup with the best competitors from the qualifying round.
>
>   The programmer **seeded** fresh, uncorrupted data into the database before running unit tests.*

The usage in sports, especially in tennis, is also worth mentioning.

> 6. To be able to compete (especially in a quarter-final/semi-final/final).
>      *The tennis player **seeded** into the quarters+tennis*.
>
> [Sporting](https://www.etymonline.com/word/seed) (originally tennis) sense (1898) is from notion of spreading certain players' names so as to ensure they will not meet early in a tournament. (Etymonline)

Comment: Good point! I was thinking only about gardening/farming.

Comment: @Mick That's why I asked. I mainly know "seeding" from its technical usage. But then I recently got a card game with an agricultural focus, and all of a sudden "sowing" popped up ;)

Comment: Quoting without correctly attributing may leave you open to copyright infringement actions, and is certainly unwelcome on ELU. Wiktionary, I believe.

Answer (score 9):

I would just point out that while you can "sow the seeds", you should not "seed the sows".

Comment: 'You should not "seed the sows".' Unless you're a boar.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, there are crops whose seeds are planted in a straight row (e.g.: sunflower and corn) and crops whose seeds are scattered in the field (e.g.: wheat and barley), hence the two different terms in agriculture...

Hope this helps

Guido

Comment: Hello, Guido. Thanks for sharing your expertise. I think that, for such common terms, more 'technical' (specifying) definitions _are_ for once justified. _But_, as [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sow), for instance, defines 'sow' thus: _plant (seed) by **scattering** it on or in the earth_ and [RHK Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/seed) defines 'seed': ... _(16) to sow or **scatter** (seed)_ , [bolding mine] you need to give supporting references for these specialised usages.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain contexts where the verb *seed* is more appropriate than *sow*.  One example is seeding rainclouds.  Here, what is being scattered in the raincloud is not seeds, but crystals of some chemical that serves as a nucleus for a water droplet.